# Why is outermost of triple-nested for loops only looping once?

Tags: java, android

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
           try {
```

this is the outer loop

```
               for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
```

the inner loop is only to delay

```
                  for (int f = 0; f < 5000; f++) { 
                       for(int k=0;i<1000;i++);

                   }
```

This is not repeating itself.

```
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hey" + i, 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               }
           }
           catch(Exception e){
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

       }
   });
```

Comment: I highly recommend you remove both your inner loops and replace with Thread.sleep(ms)--in general never delay with coded loops.  If you must use a loop for a delay, throw a Thread.sleep(10) or something in the middle just to make it more friendly.

Comment: Looping instead of `wait/sleep/timer` is a very bad idea. You also have `for(int k=0;i<1000;i++)` instead of `for(int k=0;k<1000;k++)`.

Comment: Neither Thread.sleep(), nor event Handler is working. I  have multiple images I want to show them one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are increasing `i` beyond the border of the outer loop, when it is 1000 it is easily greater than 13.

```
for(int k=0;i<1000;i++);
```

Next time the outer loop checks, the condition is false, the loop ends after only making output once.

You probably want

```
for(int k=0;k<1000;k++);
```

But (credits to Elliott Frisch) what you really want is probably something which really waits some specified time. Empty loops, like what I assume you tried, can get optimised away and therefor turn out not to have any noticable effect. Consider using a call to `sleep()`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I picked that up, hope you are fine with that.

Comment: Maybe add another example using `Thread.sleep`, otherwise good answer.

Comment: Yes. A timer is also a good choice. Although we might further add that timer on the dismissal of the previous toast. Nice answer.